# Piping Error - Observable<any> is not assignable to type Observable<number>

Tags: typescript, rxjs, observable

Why does returning `interval(500)` throw the following type error in the code below?

```js
const source = timer(0, 5000);
const example = source.pipe(switchMap(() => interval(500)));
const subscribe = example.subscribe(val => console.log(val));
```

[StackBlits](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-eb62ap?file=index.ts&devtoolsheight=100)

> Argument of type 'UnaryFunction<Observable<number>, Observable<number>>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'OperatorFunction'.
>
> Types of parameters 'source' and 'source' are incompatible.
>
> Type 'Observable<any>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<number>'.
>
> Property 'source' is protected but type 'Observable<T>' is not a class derived from 'Observable<T>'.

*This is the from the first switchMap [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-eb62ap?file=index.ts&devtoolsheight=100) found on learnrxjs.io.*

Comment: I think it is a problem in the configuration of the stackblitz you use. Try this https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-bbrzza and you should not see the issue any more

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that `timer` is defined to emit number values. So, `source` will also assume number values will be emitted. However, `switchMap` makes no assumptions about what type will be emitted by the returned observable (hence the `any`). This means that your source goes from emitting numbers to emitting anything at all.

A simple solution is this

```
import { timer, interval } from 'rxjs';
import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

//emit immediately, then every 5s
const source = <any>timer(0, 5000); //Here, we say that source can emit anything
//switch to new inner observable when source emits, emit items that are emitted
const example = source.pipe(switchMap(() => interval(500)));
//output: 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9...0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
const subscribe = example.subscribe(val => console.log(val));
```